# batch slow down .mov speed

Tags: .mov, mediaplayback

So I have a simple problem, taking a large number of .mov files and slowing them down to half speed. For the life of me I can't seem to find a simple solution to my simple problem. I don't need to rename them, change the frame rate, or anything fancy, just slow down a large number of .mov files to half speed. I've looked into software and avisynth to maybe help, but nothing seem to do what I need. Any suggestions?

Comment: "taking a large number of .mov files and slowing them down to half speed. "
What this means? Slowing down them to half speed.?
Also can you tell what homework you did?

Comment: The issue doesn't matter anymore, but I wanted to take some video files from a camera that were in a .mov format and slow them down to half speed. The problem is I have over 1000 videos. I was researching into software such as qt change and premiere but from what I can find nothing will slow down a large number of videos without constant monitoring.

Comment: Correct, probably you will need some more advanced softwares or may need to get one developments.
Microsoft Expression Encoder, Quark Softwares etc.. which can help to achieve your goal

Comment: I've been looking to possible a linux video editor that I can use the terminal for, any suggestions are appreciated. If I could script it in ubuntu then that would save me days of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problems and solved it by remuxing and changing the frame rate to half. This can be done using [tsMuxer](http://www.videohelp.com/software/tsMuxeR), which has a command line interface. Downside is it can not output in MOV format, but in m2ts or ts. I wrote a simple python script to find all MOV files in the current directory, generate the input file to tsMuxer with framerate according to input and run it. Probably exists better ways, but this is one way.

```
import os
import sys

allFilesAndFolders = os.listdir(".")
cwd = os.getcwd()
fps = sys.argv[1]
filename = "Slower.META"

for entry in allFilesAndFolders:
    if entry.endswith(".MOV"):

        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            os.remove(filename)

        with open(filename, "a+") as myFile:
            myFile.write("MUXOPT --no-pcr-on-video-pid --new-audio-pes --vbr  --vbv-len=500\n")
            myFile.write("V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC, \"" + cwd + "\\" + entry + "\", fps=" + fps + ", insertSEI, contSPS, ar=As source, track=1\n")

        os.system("\"C:\Program Files (x86)\\tsMuxeR_2.6.12\\tsMuxeR.exe\" " + filename + " " + entry.split(".")[0] + "_slow.m2ts")
```