# Apple Quick Time Mov Files Slow Down Playback Rate Via Command Line

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, movieclip, quicktime, .mov

I am looking for commmandline to slow down Quick Time formated MOV files.  Most likely using FFMPEG.  I do not mind converting to MP4 format either.

To slow down your video, you have to use a multiplier greater than 1:

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mov -filter:v "setpts=2.0*PTS" output.mov
```

I am not sure if this works right now.

[batch slow down .mov speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160172/batch-slow-down-mov-speed) (No answer here either)

Answer (score 0):

Almost impossible without full reencoding (or transcondig).

If the source is video only, it can be easily done by simple hex editing. Just change the track timescale value in the MDHD box =>
http://wiki.multimedia.cx/?title=QuickTime_container#mdhd
The lower timescale the slower play rate.

I've tested it works as following:
1) find out current frame rate with [Mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) tool
2) Open the file with [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)
3) Recklessly search 'mdhd'
4) Between 'mdhd' and 'hdlr', find 16 bit big endian hex representation of frame rate and change it

I'm not sure but this kind of hacking seems not supported by ffmpeg.

But if it also has audio track, changing its timescale will produce noisy sound, therefore reencoding is unavoidable.

Transcoding is rather straightforward work. I'd recommend [HandBreak](https://handbrake.fr/) or other GUI frontends.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv

I used this link
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video